# An error <exception str() failed> from usage of pyzillow

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used the pyzillow package to scrape the information of a house. But I kept having an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wangguijie/Documents/Codes/日常python/zilloww/zillowscraping.py", line 21, in <module>
    updated_property_details_response = zillow_data.get_updated_property_details(zpid = Zillow_id)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzillow/pyzillow.py", line 43, in get_updated_property_details
    return self.get_data(url, params)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzillow/pyzillow.py", line 82, in get_data
    raise ZillowError(int(response.findall('message/code')[0].text))
pyzillow.pyzillowerrors.ZillowError: <exception str() failed>
```

I just don't know where I was wrong.

```
from pyzillow.pyzillow import ZillowWrapper, GetDeepSearchResults, GetUpdatedPropertyDetails
address = '16366 Brisk Breeze Aly,Winter Garden, FL'
zipcode = '34787'
zillow_data = ZillowWrapper('X1-********')
deep_search_response = zillow_data.get_deep_search_results(address,zipcode)


result = GetDeepSearchResults(deep_search_response)
print(result.zillow_id)
print(type(result.zillow_id))
print(result.home_type)

Zillow_id = result.zillow_id
print(type(Zillow_id))
print(Zillow_id)
Zillow_data = ZillowWrapper('X1-*******')
updated_property_details_response = zillow_data.get_updated_property_details(zpid = Zillow_id)
result = GetUpdatedPropertyDetails(updated_property_details_response)
# print(48749425)
print(result.home_type)
```

If I used another Zillow_id such as "48749425", I didn't get any error and everything was fine. But if I used the Zillow_id subtracted from the result got by GetDeepSearchResults, it kept reporting me this error. I don't know where I am wrong. Could anyone help? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you upload the whole error traceback?

Comment: @funie200 Thank you for asking! I edited the question.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ZIllow's API, but if that's your API key in the post you may want to remove it and consider that key compromised.